# Symfony installation problems

Tags: php, symfony1, zend-server

I'm trying to set up Symfony on my 64-bit Vista laptop that's using Zend Server CE for an all-in-one PHP stack.  I'm trying to configure it with Netbeans as the IDE but I keep getting an error when I try to create a Symfony project; I've pointed it to my PHP.exe file located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\ZendServer\bin\php.exe` and my symfony.bat located in `C:\Users\Wayne\Frameworks\symfony\data\bin\symfony.bat`.  Netbeans gives me a generic "Cannot create symfony project" error, so I tried to check it manually and create the project.  This gives me an error `call to undefined function token_get_all()`, which seems to reference the built-in tokenizer for PHP 5.  Checking my PHP extensions in Zend, tokenizer is enabled and the php_tokenizer.dll is where it should be, so I'm not sure why this isn't working right.

Any ideas?  I'll gladly provide more information if necessary.  I'm using the latest version of Zend Server CE with PHP 5.3.2, so tokenizer should be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the CLI and the webserver may use different php.ini files. Do a `php -i > info.txt` to check the CLI's settings (including the .ini file it uses).

Comment: Ah ha, looking at that tells me the problem; by default Zend Server disabled the tokenizer (argument "--disable-tokenizer" is given), even though the extension is enabled.

Comment: Might try to download php from the original site, and update zend's version with that. Don't forget to make a backup. If that doesn't help, try xampp, it's a standard apache-php-mysql stack very easy to install and use.

Comment: So the tokenizer is enabled but the "configure command" portion lists "disable-tokenizer" as being a compilation option.  I don't remember being able to specify this when I installed Zend Server.  Can this be the cause?